# stdClass object and foreach loops - campaign monitor api

Tags: php, api, foreach, campaign-monitor

I am currently working within the campaign monitor api.

Here is my code:

```
require_once '../../csrest_general.php';

$auth = array('api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$wrap = new CS_REST_General($auth);

$result = $wrap->get_clients();

echo "Result of /api/v3/clients\n<br />";
if($result->was_successful()) {
    echo "Got clients\n<br /><pre>";
    var_dump($result->response);
} else {
    echo 'Failed with code '.$result->http_status_code."\n<br /><pre>";
    var_dump($result->response);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

This outputs the following:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
    ["ClientID"]=>
    string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(12) "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
    ["ClientID"]=>
    string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(15) "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }

}
```

How do i go about putting this into a foreach loop? when i try the following:

```
foreach ($result as $result->response) {
     echo $result;
}
```

i get this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class CS_REST_Wrapper_Result could not be converted to string

Comment: `foreach($result->response as $entry) { echo $entry->ClientID; }`

Comment: thanks mark! You should of posted this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Mark Butler for answering this, so I've added his solution:

```
foreach($result->response as $entry) { echo $entry->ClientID; }
```

In general terms, getting at the contents of Campaign Monitor results requires you to access the response->Results part of the object returned from the method. Unfortunately, this is not clear from the API or documentation which tends to just 'print_var' the objects returned from the method calls.

For example, listing subscribers in a list:

```
require_once '/csrest_lists.php';
$sList = new CS_REST_Lists(YOUR_CM_LIST_ID,YOUR_CM_ACCT_KEY);
$sSubscribers = $sList->get_active_subscribers()->response->Results; // return results
foreach($sSubscribers as $s) {
    echo $s->EmailAddress . "\t" . $s->Name . "\t" . $s->State . "\n";
}
```

Hope this is useful to people - thanks danyo for the question - there are few of these on SO at the moment.
Pete

Comment: If you prefer to work with arrays, you can also cast the stdObject to an array -- $result = (array) $result->response;